# Android AutoComplete with custom filter having duplicate results

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-filterable

Good day, I have this custom adapter with a filterable interface implemented and am getting duplicate values in the resulting list.

**SearchAutoCompleteAdapter.java**

```
public class SearchAutoCompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private ArrayList<BaseAutocompleteItems> resultList;
    List<BaseAutocompleteItems> filteredProducts;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    SearchAutoCompleteAPI searchautocomplete = new SearchAutoCompleteAPI();

    public SearchAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = resource;
        filteredProducts = new ArrayList<BaseAutocompleteItems>();
        resultList = new ArrayList<BaseAutocompleteItems>();
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null);

        }

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggestion_text_id);

        name.setText(resultList.get(position).getName());


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {


                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                List<BaseAutocompleteItems> tempfilteredProducts = new ArrayList<BaseAutocompleteItems
                filteredProducts.clear();

                if (constraint != null || constraint.length() > 0) {
                    tempfilteredProducts.clear();

                    tempfilteredProducts = searchautocomplete.autocomplete(constraint.toString());  //webservice call
                } else {

                    tempfilteredProducts = new ArrayList<BaseAutocompleteItems>();

                }

                    for (BaseAutocompleteItems items : tempfilteredProducts) {

                        if (items.getName().contains(constraint.toString())) {

                            filteredProducts.add(items);
                             }
                        }

                        filterResults.values = filteredProducts;
                        filterResults.count = filteredProducts.size();

                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults (CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results){

                    resultList = (ArrayList<BaseAutocompleteItems>)results.values;
                    if(results.count > 0)  {

                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {

                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            }

            ;
            return filter;
        }

    }
```

If I type "yell" and press backspace for "yel" or increase my char to "yello", I get the same result and thus the `ArrayList` ends up with duplicated items. I have tried clearing the lists before populating the list but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (constraint != null || constraint.length() != 0)`?

Comment: @user87049 typo error should be constraint.lenght() > 0.. still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
if (items.getName().contains(constraint.toString()))
```

to

```
if (items.getName().startsWith(constraint.toString()))
```

Comment: i have tried that before and i still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the code in the question. just a checklist for anyone first. make sure you call Clear() on the ArrayList being returned in the line.

```
tempfilteredProducts = searchautocomplete.autocomplete(constraint.toString());  //webservice call
```

from the API call first before populating the values from the webservice and sending it back to tempfilteredProducts(i.e before every api request). That way you avoid duplicate values from the autocompletetextview string as in my case in the question.